# Freemarker: access public field with no getter in template

Tags: java, freemarker, dropwizard, public-members, dropwizard-templates

I'm setting up views in a Dropwizard app and ran into a curious issue with Freemarker.

Following the [docs here](https://www.dropwizard.io/1.3.12/docs/manual/views.html) I set up a very simple example as follows

```java
public class ExampleFreemarkerView extends View {
  private Foo foo;

  public ContractHtmlView(Foo Foo) {
    super("FooView.ftl");
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  public Contract getFoo() { return foo };
}

public class Foo {
  public String bar = "Hello World";
}
```

With `FooView.ftl`

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>${foo.bar}</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Expected output when rendering `ExampleFreemarkerView` is an HTML document displaying `Hello World`.

What actually happens is Freemarker throws an exception, complaining that `${foo.bar}` - specifically `bar` - is undefined.

This appears to be because `bar` is a public field, without a getter. When I add a `public String getBar() { return bar; }` getter to `Foo`, it works.

I'm somewhat surprised that this is the case - i.e. that Freemarker seems to require getters and won't work with public fields out of the box. I'm deliberately using public fields instead of getters/setters on my model objects, so adding getters just to make Freemarker work isn't a solution I'll consider.

I've googled around a lot and read through the Freemarker docs, and just can't find any way to 'turn on' this behaviour in Freemarker. **Is it possible?**

Just for interest - I also tried the above example, exactly the same, but with a Mustache template and public fields work fine there (i.e. `{{foo.bar}}` renders `Hello World` without issue). That solves the immediate problem, so this question is mostly just out of curiosity or in case I decide to use Freemarker over Mustache for other reasons.

---

**Edit based on comments** - *I understand that Freemarker does this (insists on getters out the box) to follow the Java Beans spec, but most libraries in the Java ecosystem support public fields - Hibernate and Jackson being prominent examples - to the extent I personally view it as an equally valid standard and find libraries not supporting it out the box surprising.*

Comment: Can you explain why *using public fields instead of getters/setters*?

Comment: So firstly note that this is specifically for data classes, i.e. model objects - I find that no encapsulation or abstraction is necessary here. The only purpose of the class is to hold data - it's completely dumb and doesn't need to do any magic like validation or anything else. For such classes, I feel it's cleaner & simpler to just use public fields. [This answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/261868/187440) also does a good job of explaining it in more words than I can use here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This all depends on the `objectWrapper` configuration setting. The `DefaultObjectWrapper` (and any `BeansWrapper` subclass), which most projects are using, has an `exposeFields` setting that can be set to `true`.

In Dropwizard, that can be done like this in the configuration YML, if you set up your `ViewBundle` in a compatible manner (based on https://github.com/apache/freemarker-online-tester):

```
viewRendererConfiguration:
  freemarker:  # was `.ftl:` before Dropwizard 1.3.0
    objectWrapper=DefaultObjectWrapper(2.3.28, exposeFields=true)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's stated in [freemarker docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_misc_beanwrapper.html)

> Every object will be wrapped into a TemplateHashModel that will expose JavaBeans properties and methods of the object. This way, you can use model.foo in the template to invoke obj.getFoo() or obj.isFoo() methods. (Note that **public fields are not visible directly; you must write a getter method for them**.)

Notice that it's also follow [java encapsulation concept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors)

Also you can use framework as lombok [getters](https://projectlombok.org/features/GetterSetter) automatically using only class annotation

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I probably didn't state it clearly enough in the question but I know this is the case out the box, and understand why (following the java beans spec etc). What I'm interested in is if there's a way of configuring Freemarker so that public fields *are* visible directly, or if it's some sort of explicit philosophical hard no for the library. I can't find such a statement anywhere in the docs, so just curious.